# Structure morphism of a $k-$scheme is universally open

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here is from Vakil's FOAG,Page 266:[image]

And I don't understand the last step of the proof of Lemma 9.5.6 which he quotes proposition 9.5.4 without requiring $B$ is of finite type over $k$,so the conditions of the proposition fails.

Comment: Can't you just use the same trick with $B$ and replace it with $B'$ generated by the $b_i$?

Comment: No,$\phi$ doesn't factor through $Spec(A'\otimes B')$

Comment: Your question's title seems like it ought to say "universally open" instead of "universally connected". Or is there some reason you wrote "universally connected"?

Comment: @KReiser thanks,i have edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has come up somewhat recently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3627781/question-about-when-a-projection-from-a-fiber-product-is-open). Let me turn the relevant discussion from the comments in to an answer.

$\operatorname{Spec} A'\otimes_k B\to \operatorname{Spec} B$ is a flat morphism of finite presentation and thus open (ref [Stacks 01UA](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01UA), for instance). Vakil's proof suggested in exercise 24.5.G proves this in the case that the target is locally noetherian, and this assumption is actually unnecessary. (It can be removed with slightly more care around constructible sets, which the Stacks Project exercises.) So this is a slight inaccuracy in Vakil's text, but it's not so hard to fix.